# How can i add underline to a textString which comes/changes dynamically as am using xml-jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-xml

i wanted the XML attributes values which comes on page using Jquery should get underline at specific Character.

can any one please help me on this.?

Thank you in advance.

```
$(menuGroup).append('<a href="#" id="'+menuGroupName+'" onclick="SearchByDE(this.id)" title="'+menuTooltipNote+'" accesskey="'+menuAccessKey+'" class="hasSubMenu left_nav_menu">'+'<p style="padding-top:6px;">'+menuGroupName+'</p>'+'</a>');
```

Comment: have seen problem solution here but how can make sure that in my query http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6444183/style-a-certain-character-in-a-string

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. What is your XML data and how does it relate to the above code? What jQuery UI widget are you using/

Comment: XML stored menu items will come as Menu. For Menu, Submenu items i have mapped shortcuts. i want to show the Shortcut by underlining the char which part of string.

Comment: XML store data has to comes as menu. i have mapped keys and i want to underline a char which is part of the string. Eg: assume Vijay is the string, how can put a underline for V only. pls advise...

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
.accesskey { text-decoration: underline; }
```

JS:

```
var accessIndex = menuGroupName.indexOf(menuAccessKey);
menuID = menuGroupName;
if (accessIndex !== null) {
    menuGroupName = menuGroupName.substr(0, accessIndex-1) + '<span class="accesskey">' +
                    menuAccessKey + '</span>' + menuGroupName.substr(accessIndex+1);
}
$(menuGroup).append('<a href="#" id="'+menuID+'" onclick="SearchByDE(this.id)" title="'+menuTooltipNote+'" accesskey="'+menuAccessKey+'" class="hasSubMenu left_nav_menu">'+'<p style="padding-top:6px;">'+menuGroupName+'</p>'+'</a>');
```

I still don't see any dependency on XML in this. Maybe the menu data comes from XML, but I don't see how that matters for the formatting.

Comment: still am not able, as such when i try this in my page displaying entire html component(anchor tag) with details.. am not sure why..

Comment: Anchor text is normally underlined, did you change the CSS to override this so only the access key will be underlined?

Comment: yes, i have put that also in jsp page inside <style></style>. No impact seen. :(

Comment: Try it now. I didn't notice that you were using `menuGroupName` as the ID, I added a new variable for that.

Comment: i have solved this,

`var part1=menuGroupName.substr(0,indexStart);`
`var part2 = menuGroupName.charAt(indexStart);`
`part2 = '<u>'+part2+'</u>';`
`var part3 = menuGroupName.substr(indexEnd);`
   
`var menuGroupNameChanged = part1+part2+part3;`

the final value can be added and resultant text comes up with underline.

Comment: I think that should be the same. `<u>` is frowned upon these days, CSS classes are preferred.

Comment: may be but when i try using Css classes based code, it did not work. Anyways, Thanks a lot.